# Rails Nested Form Attributes Building

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

I'm having real difficulty understanding how to go about a nested form that I have. A user would sign into the application, click 'create a team' and this page would allow users to enter a team name and a list of members for the team. (effectively creating a team member list).

- I have a nested form which contains `fields_for` memberships so as to create the membership. [See screenshot of form](http://cl.ly/NhQH)
- When the form is saved, the membership model runs `Entrant.find_or_creates_by_name` to create the entrant.
- The problem I'm having is that on the creation I get the error messages:

  - Memberships team can't be blank

**How do I prevent this from happening and allow users to add entrants / ensure the membership is created correctly?**

Apologies if this has already been answered, (there seems to be many topics on has_many through with nested resources, but none that I could find dealt with my specific issue (I could / seemed to be unclear)

---

**My create action is currently the standard nested form action as follows:**

```
def create
  @user = current_user
  @team = @user.teams.build(params[:team])
  if @team.save
    redirect_to(team_url(@team), :notice => "Team was successfully saved")
  else
    render :action => "new"
  end
end
```

**I have the following models:**

User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :teams
end
```

Team Model

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :entrants, :through => :memberships

  attr_accessible :name, :team_type, :website, :memberships_attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :memberships, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Memberships Model

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team
  belongs_to :entrant

  validates :team_id, presence: true
  validates :entrant_id, presence: true

  attr_accessor :entrant_name
  attr_accessible :entrant_name 

  def entrant_name
    entrant && entrant.name
  end

  def entrant_name=(name)
    self.entrant = Entrant.find_or_create_by_name(name) unless name.blank?
  end

end
```

Entrants Model - This is effectively a member of the team for memberlistings however when a user enters a team they can specify nickname which may change across teams.

```
class Entrant < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :teams, :through => :memberships
end
```

Comment: Additional Info / files to help with the question: [Form View Code](https://gist.github.com/digitaldawn/fc2edc87dbbe5889ffb9) | [Development Log](https://gist.github.com/digitaldawn/c98dd9789094098258eb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its a validation error. Try to remove
validates :entrant_id, presence: true
From membership model.

Comment: Sure, but then the membership wouldn't exist as the membership is the join model between entrants and teams?

Comment: When you use accepts_nested_attributes_for the parent id and child id are automatically generated for corresponding parent and child model when you save the record.